# Confusion on the definition of Simple connectedness

Tags: algebraic-topology

The problem I am working on asks me to prove that

> $X$ is simply connected iff any two paths in $X$ is path-homotopic.

If I'm not mistaken, I need two conditions for simple connectedness. (i) $X$ is path-connected (ii) fundamental group is trivial.

For the reverse direction of this proof, I'm stuck on proving (i) $X$ is path-connected. In the extreme case, if there are just two discrete points in $X$ in the metric space, it wouldn't contradict the condition that any two paths in $X$ is path-homotopic (vacuously holds) while failing the (i) condition.
I just want to know if the question lacks some additional condition or there is some misunderstanding about the definition of simple-connectedness. I would appreciate any of your comments.

Comment: Your claim about the two-point case is false. In order for two paths to be homotopic they must in particular be in the same path component.

Comment: Yes, you are right, you need to assume $X$ is path connected. Also, path homotopy is possible only when two paths have the same initial and end points. So the correct statement should be "$X$ is simply connected if and only if between any two points in $X$ there is a path, and it is unique up to path homotopy".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is wrong.

First, the condition "any two paths in $X$ is path-homotopic" cannot be satisfied unless $X$ has a single point. As pointed by Gae. S. in his answer, path homotopy requires that paths have the same endpoints. Thus the author was imprecise. We can study two precisions:

1. Any two paths with the same endpoints are path-homotopic.
2. Any two paths are freely homotopic.

But 2. does not characterize simple connectedness, it only characterizes path connectedness. This comes from the fact that each path is freely homotopic to a constant path, and constant paths are freely homotopic iff their images are contained in the same path component of $X$.

Variant 1. performs better, it characterizes spaces $X$ in which all path components are simply connected. However, if $X$ is not path connected, then it is not simply connected.

Thus it is correct to state

> $X$ is simply connected iff it is path connected and satisfies 1.